Shadow Artifacts on Plane Below a Sphere
I am having this minor issue implementing shadow mapping. The plane below the sphere has these strange artifacts. I can fix it by offsetting the position slightly but I'd rather have it work automatically because it will be using physics.



Debugging questions should include enough information to recreate the problem also known as a minimum complete verifiable example. This helps the community focus on answers that can solve your problem rather speculating on solutions unrelated to your situation. Please edit to include the necessary details.

This question can be closed. But for anyone else who runs into this problem, the problem was using front face culling instead of shadow bias. Multiplying the bias by the dot product of the normal and the light position eliminated all artifacts.
